# DirectX when I add a texture to a quad the triangles mess up somehow, fix?

Tags: c++, geometry, directx, textures

First of all here are the important parts of my code.

Creating the vertices.

```
D3DVertexTexture Vertices[] =
{
    {-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
    { 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, },
    {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
};
```

Creating the vertex buffer.

```
D3DDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(Vertices),
                              0,
                              D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEXTEXTURE,
                              D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                              &vb,
                              NULL);
```

Memory crap.

```
void* pVoid;

vb->Lock(0, sizeof(pVoid), (void**) &pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, Vertices, sizeof(Vertices));
vb->Unlock();
```

Loading the texture.

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(D3DDevice, "images/tex.png", &t);
```

Rendering.

```
D3DDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEXTEXTURE);

D3DDevice->SetTexture(0, t);
D3DDevice->SetStreamSource(0, vb, 0, sizeof(D3DVertexTexture));
D3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
```

Where is my problem.

It shows a square but the left side of the side is missing in a triangular shape like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Vertices A,B,C,D in a triangle strip will produce two triangles: A,B,C and B,C,D

```
A -- B  A--B     B
|    |   \ |    /|
|    |    \|   / |
D -- C     C  D--C
```

Look at that diagram and picture those two triangles...

Then go and put your vertices in the right order - triangle strips should 'zig-zag', not proceed in clockwise or anti-clockwise order.

If you order them: A,B,D,C - the quad will draw correctly.

Comment: Hmm I tried putting 6 vertices for 2 triangles and still didn't work, I did that before I saw this though but about a min before I saw this I fixed it i changed D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP to D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN

Comment: Not the best fix. TRIANGLEFAN is an awkward primitive, it pretty much limits you to a single polygon per draw-call, which is really bad performance wise. You just needed to swap two vertices over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining you vertices in this order:

```
D3DVertexTexture Vertices[] =
{
    { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, },
    {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
    {-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
    { 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
};
```

I believe the order in wich vertices are drawn is by default the clockwise order. You are defining in an incorrect order.